# Objective C custom compare: with priority

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSArray of countries that I obtained using `[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]`. How do I sort this NSArray such that I can put certain **commonly used countries** at the top of the list, while keeping the rest in its alphabetical order?

```
United States of America
United Kingdom
Singapore
Korea
Japan
Hong Kong
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
etc etc..
```

I am using `caseInsensitiveCompare:` currently to get the alphabetical order, but how can I change it such that I can specify a list to put at the top, while the rest to be kept alphabetical below.

Comment: I think you need to define `common countries` yourself. If you come from Albania then it is `common` to you.

Comment: yes I understand `common` has to be defined by myself. but how can I write the `compare:` such that it puts what I want at the top?

Comment: I would use a dictionary and make each country name a key, and store a priority value for each item. Maybe priority zero means top of list and any other value means sort alphabetically or whatever you want.  Something like that.

Comment: Use NSSortDescriptor. Then you can specify multiple factors on which, you want to sort and what gets priority first. For clarity, I provided the complete solution to your problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the objects you do not want to sort,then sort the rest,then add them together.
Example Code:

```
NSMutableArray * allData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]]];
NSArray * yourexceptArray;
[allData removeObjectsInArray:yourexceptArray];
NSMutableArray * result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:yourexcepArray];
sortedArray = //Sort the allData as you like,then add it to result
[result addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray]
```

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to WenchenHuang's answer (which is valid), I think you could do it with the help of `sortedArrayUsingComparator`. 
Inside the block just compare the strings as usually, but if the string equals to one of the codes that you want to show higher, return `YES`.

```
someArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([(NSString*)obj1 isEqualToString:@"USA"]) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([(NSString*)obj1 isEqualToString:@"SOME_OTHER_COUNTRY"]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:(NSString*)obj2];
}];
```

Comment: yeah this is the method I have in mind but I cant seem to find any applicable syntax online that compares two strings.

Comment: @chongzixin the string comparison is right there on the last line (`[(NSString*)obj1 compare:(NSString*)obj2]`)

Comment: This would be done better using two separate sort descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using Sort Descriptor. I don't like manipulating array again and again. So, I find sort descriptors best in this kind of scenario. (Just personal preference)

Step 1: Create a model class with priority as a key. My model class-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ISOCountry : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *countryCode;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *priority;

@end
```

Step 2: The just do this-

```
NSArray *ISOCountryCodes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]];
NSArray *commonUsedCountries= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"NR", @"NG", @"KW", @"ES", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrayToBeSorted = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSString *countryCode in ISOCountryCodes){

    ISOCountry *isoCountry = [[ISOCountry alloc] init];
    [isoCountry setValue:countryCode forKey:@"countryCode"];

    if(![commonUsedCountries containsObject:countryCode]){
        [isoCountry setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2] forKey:@"priority"];
       }
    else{
        [isoCountry setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1] forKey:@"priority"];
       }
   [arrayToBeSorted addObject:isoCountry];
}

NSSortDescriptor *prioritySort =    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *countryCodeSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"countryCode"  ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:prioritySort, countryCodeSort, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayToBeSorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```